# wine staging 1.9.7 not run application after compilation

Tags: wine

I have download normal wine(1.9.7) and then apply wine staging patch on it(v1.9.7). Then compile wine. And then If I install any application then it show me below things only.

```
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.9.7 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
```

My os version is : Lubuntu16.04 (64 bit)

Answer (score 2):

This is not unusual. I say this to so many people. **Read the message!**

So just do what it says!

It is telling you it is an experimental version. The other one says to say it is a experimental version when filing a bug!

Comment: what is meaning?

Comment: You applied the staging patch. This is a experimental version.